# Laravel remove quotes from variable in database query

Tags: php, sql, laravel, join

I'm constructing a RAW database query with Laravel (5.4) and I'm getting a problem in that laravel is placing quotes in the SQL output for a variable within a join... The result is that mysql thinks that the variable... Which for example would output to 1 or something numeric is a column and outputs error "Cannot find column '1' in ON clause

### PROBLEM SQL CLAUSE:

->join('event_jury_sub_detail', function($join) use($userid)
                        {
                        $join->on('event_jury_sub_detail.evtpartsub_id', '=', 'event_partsubmissions.id')
                            ->on('event_jury_sub_detail.authoruser_id','=',$userid);

Problem: $userid gets quotes... And becomes "and `event_jury_sub_detail`.`authoruser_id` = `1`" - Laravel treats it as a column to look up and fails.

If the quotes are removed it works fine... How to resolve this?

FULL QUERY

```
$tbl_return = DB::table('event_partsubmissions')
            ->select(DB::raw('event_partsubmissions.*,
                                users.usr_firstnames,
                                users.usr_surnames,
                                users.email,
                                users.usr_nationality,
                                users.usr_country,
                                event_jury_sub_detail.id as evtjurysubdetid,
                                event_jury_sub_detail.evtjurysubdet_pointsawarded,
                                event_jury_sub_detail.evtjurysubdet_notes,
                                event_jury_sub_detail.evtjurysubdet_randomkey
                            '))
            ->join('event_participation', 'event_partsubmissions.evtpartsub_evtpartid', '=', 'event_participation.id')                
            ->join('users', 'evtpart_userid', '=', 'users.id')
            ->join('event_jury_sub_detail', function($join) use($userid)
                    {
                    $join->on('event_jury_sub_detail.evtpartsub_id', '=', 'event_partsubmissions.id')
                        ->on('event_jury_sub_detail.authoruser_id','=',$userid);                        
                    })
            ->where('event_partsubmissions.evtpartsub_evtid', '=', $id)
            ->where('event_partsubmissions.evtpartsub_enabled', '>=', $partlevel)
            ->where('event_participation.evtpart_enabled', '>=', 1) 
            ->where('event_participation.evtpart_level', '>=', 100)  
            ->where('users.usr_enabled', '>=', 1)  
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the alias for table joins:

```
->join('event_jury_sub_detail as ejsd', ...
```

And use the alias in following places:

```
->$join->on('ejsd.evtpartsub_id', '=', 'event_partsubmissions.id')
```

For scalar params in join conditions, you can use DB wrapper like `DB::raw($userid)`:

```
->on('ejsd.authoruser_id','=',DB::raw($userid));
```

Comment: It's a good suggestion, but unfortunately doesn't solve this particular problem. Applying those aliases still results in error " SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '1' in 'on clause' (SQL: select event_partsubmissions.*

Comment: So basically what's happening here is the $userid variable in the join clause becomes `authoruser_id` = `1` and mysql fails the query thinking that '1' is a column to be looked up.

Comment: @stoneferry You can move the `->on('event_jury_sub_detail.authoruser_id','=',$userid);` part (or `->on('ejsd.authoruser_id','=',$userid);` with alias) to `where` section without any problems, try it! In result it may looks like: `->where('ejsd.authoruser_id','=',$userid);`

Comment: Thanks again for the suggestion, actually I cannot make that move because sometimes the row will not exist in the ejsd table, if I moved it to the 'Where' clause I would get no resultset back at all, something I do not want.

Comment: @stoneferry then you can try passing `DB::raw($userid)` as a parameter to the on() method instead of `$userId`. It is the last variant of this situation)

Answer (score 0):

use DB::raw()

->on(DB::raw("event_jury_sub_detail.authoruser_id = '".$userid."'"))